# Is there any formula for $(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i)\bigcap(\bigcup_{j\in J}B_j)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I came up with this question when doing some argument in topology. Is there any formula for $(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i)\bigcap(\bigcup_{j\in J}B_j)$? Can it be reduced in another form?

Comment: Try an easier problem - what about $A\cap (B_1 \cup B_2)$, can you express that in a different way?

Comment: @MatthewTowers Yes, but when dealing with possible infinite case, I'm always afraid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. First, let $A=\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$, then use the distributive law to write
$$A \cap \left(\bigcup_{j \in J} B_j\right) = \bigcup_{j \in J} \left(A \cap B_j\right).$$

Now $A\cap B_j = \left(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i\right) \cap B_j$, so we can again use the distributive law to write
$$A \cap B_j = \left(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i\right) \cap B_j = \bigcup_{i \in I} (A_i \cap B_j).$$

So finally,
$$\left(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i\right) \cap \left(\bigcup_{j \in J} B_j\right) = \bigcup_{i \in I } \bigcup_{j \in J} (A_i \cap B_j).$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\bigcup_{(i,j)\in I\times J}(A_i\cap B_j)$$
if you prefer that.